# evaluate `resin(x)` function in string with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I am trying to evaluate a function in a string like this `resin(8)`

so if i have this text `3*(resin(4)-sin(12))`

I need to evaluate `resin(1)` so it will replace that while occurrence with the result which should look like `392.9`

I am using this

```js
result = result.replace(/(?<={resin\()(.*?)(?=\)})/, x => parseInt(392.9 * x))
```

but i need it to replace the `resin(` part and the `)` closing parentheses.

is there any regexp magic I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead?

In my opinion, when using a regex replacer, as you did, the grouping is more than enough to accomplish the task:

```
result = result.replace(/resin\((\d+\.?\d*)\)/g, (_, x) => parseInt(392.9 * parseFloat(x)))
```

Edit:
I just read in your question that you need `resin(1)` to be replaced with `392.9`, but in your snippet you used `parseInt` and I kept it in my example. Just drop the `parseInt` in case you don't need the result to be an integer